# Black screen at CSGO

Tags: freeze, opengl

I just installed CS:GO from Steam about 5 minutes ago and launched it
but the screen is black it is frozen or something.

[image: Screenshot-CSGO]

Comment: I would be looking to Steam Support on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It starts just black, or it play a cinematic and then it goes black?

I had a similar problem where the game launchs and play a cinematic, but I couldn't see more than a black screen like yours. The thing is when it finish it appears a Close button. I noticed it while scrolling between workspaces. So to click it I changed the resolution in the launch parameters in Steam, i put "-w 1280 -h 720" and it works.

It was the experience I had. Hope it can help you.

Comment: Hello, yea worked thank you a lot ( but i have 20 fps on GT 520 with 800 * 600 resulation XD )

Comment: @xii69 I am gratefull it helped you. About fps, i don't think I can help you XD. But maybe you could try to change the drivers